# Cumulative Sum Function on Pandas Data Frame

Tags: python, pandas

I am attempting to capture a "running" cumulative sum given a series of period amounts.

See example:

[image]

```
df = df[1:4].cumsum() # this doesn't return the desired result
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking for the `axis` parameter. Many Pandas functions take this argument to apply an operation across the columns or across the rows. Use `axis=0` to apply row-wise and `axis=1` to apply column-wise. This operation is actually traversing the columns, so you want `axis=1`.

`df.cumsum(axis=1)` by itself works on your example to produce the output table.

```
In [3]: df.cumsum(axis=1)
Out[3]:
      1   2   3   4
10   16  30  41  61
51   13  29  40  50
13   11  30  45  61
321  12  27  37  52
```

I suspect you're interested in restricting to a specific range of columns, though. To do that, you can use `.loc` with the column labels (strings in mine).

```
In [4]: df.loc[:, '2':'3'].cumsum(axis=1)
Out[4]:
      2   3
10   14  25
51   16  27
13   19  34
321  15  25
```

`.loc` is label-based and is inclusive of the bounds. If you want to find out more about indexing in Pandas, check the [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html).

Answer (score 3):

You want `axis=1` to sum across the rows.

```
df.cumsum(axis=1)
```

Side-note - doing `[1:4]` slices the *rows* by default (i.e. numpy or list-like semantics).  If you want to select columns by label, use `df.loc[:, 1:4]`